# What does this egrep command do?

Tags: bash, grep

I run this command

```
egrep "\" string_demo | wc -l
```

I got output below:

```
akshay@akshay-K53SC:~/shell$ egrep "\" string_demo | wc -l
> abc
> pqr
> xyz
>
```

">" will continue until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. So what is this?

Also what is the exact difference between `grep`, `egrep` and `fgrep`?

Answer (score 5):

When you issue `egrep "\" string_demo | wc -l`, your shell is treating `\` as backslash escape and continuing to take input in the `PS2` until you enter EOF (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>).

In these cases you need to use single quotes to escape being interpreted by shell. More precisely, if you want to search for literal backslash in a file, use:

```
grep '\\' file.txt
```

Example:

```
$ grep '\\' file.txt 
eagle,dove\ ,cat
```

Here i have made two changes, firstly used single quotes (`''`) and secondly used `\\` to tell `grep` that i want to look for literal `\`, otherwise `grep` will show me the following error:

```
$ grep '\' file.txt 
grep: Trailing backslash
```

In a nutshell, you command can be written in following ways:

- Using Bash's [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

  ```
  wc -l < <(grep '\\' string_demo)
  ```
- Using usual method:

  ```
  grep '\\' string_demo | wc -l
  ```

****Don't use `egrep`, it is deprecated in favour of `grep -E`.

Check [this post of U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17949/68757) to get the differences between `grep`, `grep -E` & `grep -F`.

Comment: you mean  `grep '\\' string_demo | wc -l` !

Comment: @MAKZ could this be rewritten as wc -l < $(grep '\\' string_demo)

Comment: @Serg I also thought of that. But just tested it, and got a `ambiguous redirect` error.

Comment: @MAKZ: oops..thnaks for noticing..i was meant to use process substitution

Answer (score 1):

`egrep` searches lines with whatever you tell it to search in quotes from file , `wc -l` counts number of lines. You're basically telling egrep to count lines with backslash in them, and then let `wc -l` to count how many there are of those lines.

Comment: 1st: This is what the command *would* be doing if entered properly. The OPs question seems to be why he is being asked for more input. 2nd: spaces around a piping operator are completely unnecessary in bash, e.g. `echo hallo|wc -l` works, without spaces around the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

**">" will continue until I press Ctrl + D. So what is this?**

- > is used by bash to indicate that it expects more input. Which is why it ends only when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed, which simulates  EOF . In your command, `"\" string demo` is not a complete patteren because second `"` is escaped by `\`, and needs a terminating matching `"`.

**what is the exact difference between grep, egrep and fgrep?**

From `man egrep` :

- egrep is **the same** as grep -E.   fgrep  is  **the same**  as  grep -F.   rgrep  is  **the  same**  as  grep -r.  Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is **deprecated**, but is provided **to allow historical applications** that rely on them to run unmodified.*
- grep -E : pattern provided is an [extended regular expression](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-12).
- grep -F : pattern provided is matched verbatim
- grep -r : recursively find in all files. Directory name is provided instead of filename